# Datatables intefered with z-index CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

**Hi everyone!** I am using a side navigator in my web application. I would like this to be on the lowers lay of all the components. This is, because popovers can occur. I have noticed that the whole sidenav doesn't work anymore when I have the attribute `z-index` in my css. In other pages it still works, but on this specific page I am using datatables. Is there a attribute similar to `z-index` or a way to work around datatables?

Comment: Depth in css is managed only by `z-index` (at least I haven't seen anything similar). Also the order of the elements in the HTML DOM influences this. If you have two elements with the same `z-index`, the second one will be on top of the first.

Comment: You can add a `z-index` to this `sidenav` class that is higher than the other elements on the page. But be careful when using `z-index`. It's just like `!important`, and can be a mess.

Comment: Hmm oke.. I will try to add a top `z-index` to the pop-over and see what will happen.